# Adapter.fill(datatable) taking long time to fill data from datatable

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, datatable

I want to build export to excel functionality in my application, where in data is very huge (around 50000). When I run the query in database it takes around 10sec whereas in application to populate datatable it takes around 1.5min. 
Please guide me to retrieve data fast. I'm using VS2013 and Oracle database.
Below is the code I've tried so far

```
      DT = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(DT);   <-- This part is taking long time to fill
      ds.Tables.Add(DT);
```

Comment: don't you think that loading partially is better idea than to load the whole data collection? Such things as pagination, grouping by some fields or commands, so on.

Comment: @Khazratbek: Yes I've added pagination while displaying it in datagridview, but in case of Export to excel I want to fetch all records from database

Comment: are you sure that databinding takes so long time? May be creating of your Excel? Have you made debug without exporting to Excel?

Comment: Yes databinding takes long time, I checked without exporting to excel

Comment: Actually, DataTable takes longer time than it should due to: it indexes your table to improve the speed to use it in your code-behind. If you don't use this datatable for anything else rather than for an excel export, switch to datareader. It will work faster and you will get what you need.

Comment: @Khazratbek: I agree with you and so tried using Datareader, but it fires exception as 'Depth = Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.'. Can you please guide what is the above related to

Comment: can you post your datareader code? I mean how to call your query, how you bind data for export, so on.

Comment: 'OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PRC_GETRecieveddata_NEW"); OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            dt.Load(dr);'

Comment: Don't use DataTable at all. I said already, DataTable takes longer time to help to improve access to your data in the datatable. Use DataReader without DataTable..

Comment: Can you please guide me with small code snippet.

Comment: OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("StoredProcName", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(odr.Read() && odr.HasRows){
    //do something here
}
con.Close();

Comment: @Khazratbek : It worked!! Thanks a lot